# Dificuldade com o alinhamento de texto no botão do Ionic 2

Tags: html, ionic2, css

Iniciei meus estudos com Ionic 2 esses dias é não estou conseguindo alinhar o texto dos botões do Ionic para direita ou esquerda, ele fica apenas no centro.

1 - Tentei usar as marcações informada nos Doc do Ionic (text-left, text-right), não obtive sucesso;

2 - Tentei usar css, mas sem sucesso :

```
text-align: right; text-align: -moz-right; text-align: -webkit-right;
```

3 - Adicionei o crosswalk-webview sem sucesso;

4 - tentei mudar o HTML, sem sucesso :

```
<ion-content text-left>
    <ion-col text-left>
        <ion-row text-left>
            <button ion-button icon-left text-left class="buttons" >Para gerar a vida</button>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-col>
</ion-content>

<ion-content text-left>
    <div text-left>
        <p text-left>
            <button ion-button icon-left text-left class="buttons" >Para gerar a vida</button>
        </p>
    </div>
</ion-content>

<ion-content text-left>
    <div text-left>
        <p text-left>
            <button ion-button icon-left text-left class="buttons" ><p text-left>Para gerar a vida </p></button>
        </p>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Alguém saberia me dizer onde estou errando ?

Comment: Harlan, recomendo que você edite novamente sua pergunta e remova a parte que você adicionou informando como resolver o problema. Ao invés disso, transforme em uma resposta. Assim outros usuários que possam enfrentar o mesmo problema poderão encontrar a resposta com maior facilidade.

Comment: Celsom, como não posso aceitar a minha própria resposta como a solução do problema, apenas adicionei a nova informação que consegui na descrição do problema. 
Obrigado pela informação.

Comment: Mas você pode aceitar, mas tem que esperar um certo tempo ;)

Comment: Bom saber, vlw  :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O usuário luukschoen me respondeu no fórum do Ionic :
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/trouble-with-the-alignment-of-text-in-the-ionic-2-buttons/87552

Simplesmente estava editando a marcação errada, a correta é :

```
button-inner {
    justify-content: center;
}
```